# Bijection of simple set

Tags: computer-science, computability

Let $X$ is simple set (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_set)

$Z \subset X$ is infinite recursive set.

$Y = X$ \ $Z$.

How to prove that there is a computable  bijection $f$ that $x \in X \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in Y$?